# synchronisation on a block of code using akka

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, akka, actor, synchronization

I want to use akka in my application for multi processing. 
So, the same block of code gets executed by each actor and the results will be aggregated by the listener.
so, my question is will there be any synchronisation problem in this case. If not how is it being handled by akka actors internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default there should not be any synchronization problems - **if** you strictly respect the actor approach. This means that actors should only communicate using messages that contain immutable objects - and that you should never expose internal state of an actor to the outer world directly. Make the internal state mutable/readable solely by reacting to received messages.

Each actor is executed in its own ExecutionContext. This means that each actor has its own private state. Akka actors are designed in a way that accessing this internal state from the "outer world" is basically not possible (or made very hard) since after creating a new Actor, you only have an intermediary reference to an Actor (an ActorRef instance), not an reference to the actual Actor instance in the memory. It is intention of the Akka developers to do it that way: it is made hard for developers to get the the actual reference and access its properties directly - which would break the Actor approach.

If - on the other hand - you pass an shared mutable object to an actor, you will have all the hassle with locks and synchronization as you have for instance with using Threads.